# How to use Python packages that were installed on Python 3.5 in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, module, pip, python-module

I recently updated my python from 3.5 to 3.7. I installed multiple modules on Python 3.5 using pip. However, after updating to Python 3.7, these are no longer available.

I know that the problem is that these modules are located in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/ (OSX), which means that Python 3.7 can't reach them.

My question is, whether I have to reinstall these modules again on Python 3.7 or if there is a way for me to reach these modules easily from Python 3.7? Perhaps is there a way to install modules in such a way that they can be reached by all Python versions?

Many thanks

Comment: Do these extra modules have support for 3.7? If so you should be able to update through pip

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah for sure. E.g. Numpy is one of them. Are you saying that updating the packages would make them available on 3.7?

Comment: Yeah if the package itself has been updated (by the devs) to support the latest version of python, then installing the latest version of the package should be enough to keep your versions inline

Comment: I don't think it is a version related issue. The problem is that I installed these modules when using python 3.5 and thus they are placed in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/. This makes that python 3.7 can't find them. So I was wondering if I need to reinstall those packages for python 3.7 or if I can get python 3.7 to find these modules? Or even better, make sure that these modules are automatically available to all versions of Pyton. Doe that make sense?

Comment: Oh I see, yes in that case first thing would be to uninstall the packages and then reinstall them. That should make all of your directories line up with your current version of python. Just make sure you don't end up with 2 installs of the same module.

Comment: So you're saying that I should uninstall all the modules in the python 3.5 folder and then reinstall them in the python 3.7 folder? That seems like a lot of manual work when just updating python no?

Comment: It might be a pain sure, but as far as I can see its the safest way to make sure all of your modules are installed and carried over correctly. I won't post as an answer because somebody that knows more than me might have a quicker method for doing this. But if I were doing this I'd reinstall my modules to make sure they are all put in the right place

Comment: Do you know whether it would be a problem if I just installed the modules 'again' in python 3.7? In other words, just leave the modules in 3.5 as is and just install them again for 3.7?

Comment: It would probably be fine, but you could end up with mismatched versions of code in use if you ever made your own changes to it. Plus you're using twice the disk space.

Comment: Gotcha ok thank you very much for your help! I am still wondering though if there isn't a better way to do this...

Comment: Honestly there's every chance that there is a quicker way to do this, this is just how I personally would go about it. Keep your question up in case somebody that knows more than me can chip in with something better, but you've got my 2 cents :)

Comment: Will do! Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: No worries dude :)